# How can I copy tree folders but keep only folder named "dist" from each?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

How can I copy, using **Windows cmd** (or bat file), a tree of folders with the following structure:

Source/Folder 1/dist

Source/Folder 1/other files.. (multiple)

Source/Folder 2/dist

Source/Folder 2/other files.. (multiple)
...

The thing is I only want to keep the dist folder from each "Folder #", for example the final form to be:

Destination/Folder 1/dist

Destination/Folder 2/dist

Thanks!
ukw.

Comment: how much are folders and are they all named `Folder X`?

Comment: It's "n" folders. Not a specific number and it should work with any name the folder have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use from command line

```dos
for /d %a in ("x:\source\*") do xcopy /s /e /y /i "%~fa\dist" "x:\destination\%~nxa\dist"
```

To use inside a batch file, percent signs in `for` replaceable parameter needs to be doubled

```dos
for /d %%a in ("x:\source\*") do xcopy /s /e /y /i "%%~fa\dist" "x:\destination\%%~nxa\dist"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvoted your answer, but unfortunately, because I don't have 15 reputation yet it cant be set publicly.